# iPhone - API for Text to Speech feature

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I was wondering if iPhone has any API that supports Text to Speech feature? I looked around but couldn't find any, so just want to confirm.

Comment: Here are the list...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839671/text-to-speech-libraries-for-iphone/12839821#12839821

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I ran into this problem at one point, and got Flite (festival lite) text to speech engine running on iPhone.  I recently made an API class for it.  I tried to make it easy (and free) to add to new and existing projects.  It can be downloaded at [here](https://github.com/cmang/iPhone-TTS).

Comment: It works great with small text to speak. do u know anything which would work for even large chunks of data like reading a whole document...

Comment: This works great, but the voices are very "robotic". They made some new high quality voices, http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/onlinedemo.html. I suppose you used the diphone voices. How did you convert these to .c files?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly from the licence, that the project can also be used in commercial applications?

Comment: This library buggy and very slow on devices (long delay before hearing speech). It is probably not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: How many language does it support?

Answer (score 11):

The iPhone 3G S has the private VoiceServices framework which can do this.  Steve Troughton-Smith describes how to use the private class VSSpeechSynthesizer [here](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2009/07/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-3gs.html), but you have little chance of getting something using this into the App Store.

Comment: Ah... What i was looking for. But not very useful if its use is so limited, and doubtful (w.r.t. App Store acceptance) :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For iOS 5 or 6 - nothing built-in. You need to use a third party library.

For iOS 7 there is a [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) API.

Here's a simple example:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance 
                                speechUtteranceWithString:@"Hello world"];
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Answer (score 5):

[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) is an open-source iOS library for implementing round-trip English language speech recognition and text-to-speech on the iPhone and iPad, which uses the CMU Pocketsphinx, CMU Flite, and MITLM libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone) but i haven't tried it yet.

Comment: iSpeech is actually rather nice and and affordable solution for commercial use. I use it, and can recommend it.

Comment: This is only cloud solution. Just a side note.

Answer (score 2):

The API docs would suggest that the API is not available.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to have a look at [this](http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html).

It uses Flite. It doesn't contain specific instructions but it can give you ideas.

Comment: I tried to test it out once, but there was a web of compiler errors, and after 2 hrs, i gave up :)

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 5 or 6 - nothing built-in. You need to use a third party [library](http://www.politepix.com/openears/).

For iOS 7 there is a [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) API.

Source Code also available in Github

Refer the Below Link

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you will have to roll your own.  I have seen an app do this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this before iPhone 2.0 came out by porting espeak to the platform.  I used it as a command line utility but it should be possible to make it into a library.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use google tts:

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello

and some others:

http://www.ispeech.org/api

http://tts-api.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google TTS limited to 100 characters.

So you should split-up your long sentence in to small 100 character chunks and pass it to the Google TTS method.

You can achieve this through implementing below steps.

- Split-up your long sentence in to small 100 character chunks.
- Call Google TTS with first split 100 character string.
- Play it using Google TTS & AVAudioPlayer
- Implement AVAudioPlayer audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate .
- In that delegate, call Google TTS with second split 100 character
  string.
- Call the process recursively until reach the last character.

Here is best One for me [Google-TTS-Library-For-iOS library](https://github.com/shamsudheen/Google-TTS-Library-For-iOS) try it :)

Answer (score -2):

There's an Iphone app that does direct TTS, Search for "TTSMessenger" on Itunes