# Voice Synthesis for the iPhone

Tags: iphone

I know that Apple hasn't given access to voice recognition, but do we have access to voice synthesis. If they haven't given us an API, would it be possible to hack the accessibility APIs to work even for people with VoiceOver turned off?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time i checked, the API's required for voice synthesis (NSSynthesis) are only available on Mac OS.  The API's have not yet been ported to iphone.

I have heard a lot from this company:
http://www.acapela-group.com/acapela-for-iphone-multilingual-speech-synthesis-available-for-iphone-applications--2028-speech-synthesis.html

Their product is supposed to work quite well, although their licensing scheme is a bit steep.

Answer (score 0):

The license is a bit steep, but the text-to-speech is excellent.  At the end of the day, unless you can write your own tts engine, you are over a barrel if you app requires that feature.  I have looked at some of the free implementations and they are just not ready for prime time.  I guess  question is "Is the profit left after that percentage worth writing the application?"