# how to convert text to audio file in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing one iphone applicaion in which i want to implement below functionality.

1)User can put input text.After pressing on ok button this text should convert in audio file.
2)User can draw text on the iphone screen and after pressign ok button text should convert in auddio file.

Is it possible i dont know
Can you give me advice for that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at Acapela TTS Library

http://www.acapela-for-iphone.com/blog

Comment: User can draw text on the iphone screen and after pressign ok button text should convert in audio file. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, User will write text in textfield and clicking on button, that text will be converted into audio file

Comment: No not in text field...My question is user can draw text on the iphone screen and that shoud be convert in to audio. Should we get text from the drawn text on the iphone screen?