# Can I make iphone app speak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-audio

I have already created an application which retrievs information through web service.
Now i thought about making the **app read the titles** and the user selected content.

Can I use any **frameworks** which would help me in making the text which I select to be in speech mode ie: It should read the content as similar as **Windows speech Engine.**

Answer (score 3):

Check out the below link. It'll help you.

http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. But Flite is a third party private api and i have heard that Apple does not accept it as an api, then what should we do?

Comment: Flite isn't a private API, so there should be no issue submitting an app which uses it and it is used by many apps in the App Store (including one of my own). Here is a previous discussion on the topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature