# Equivalent to "say" on iOS?

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - API for Text to Speech feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature)

Is there any way to use the voiceover API to read out text in an iOS app? I am making a children's flash card app for practice, and want to get it to say for instance "tractor" when I show a tractor, without having to record myself!

Comment: I would seriously consider NOT doing this.  Assuming you can, you are at the mercy of whatever the system *thinks* the word is you are trying to say AND its particular method of saying it.  There have been WAY too many instances of child's toys saying inappropriate things and having to be pulled from the shelves.  If you are playing your own sound file then you are in control.

Comment: I know the author of a series of very successful iOS children's applications, and he said that his recorded voices are one of the things that helped set his application apart.  He even recorded his young daughter speaking words and numbers, which added to the charm and educational utility of the application.  I doubt a synthesized voice will be as clear as a well-recorded actual human voice.

Comment: Good point. This was a terrible late night idea!