# How to convert Speech to Text in ios SDK

Tags: ios

I am working on project its requirement is convert human voice to text , but I heard that in ios 5.1 they have added this new feature .

can any one help me to how to integrate this new feature in my application with a small example .

Thanks in Advance.
saroj.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything to integrate it into your app - any UITextField or UITextView that the user taps into brings up the keyboard, and this has a microphone icon to the immediate left of the spacebar. The user taps this, does their talking, and taps again. The speech to text is done by Apple's servers, so it takes a few seconds, maybe longer when on a slow connection. While this is happening, there will be three purple coloured circles displayed in the text field to denote that speech to text is happening. These are then replaced with the text that is returned from Apple. Note that if you have no network connection (e.g. wifi off, airplane mode, or just no mobile signal available), then the button is removed from the keyboard. So just note that you have no access to text-to-speech when offline.

Comment: Thanks a lot , can  you have any idea for lower version ios.

Comment: Hmm, it seems this feature is also only available on the new iPad, and not on previously released devices. If you want to support these (and lower versions of iOS), you'll need to use a third party library. e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature)

Comment: That's grate, I have one requirement , is it possible to send one or more lines of text to apple server to convert to voice in our app? please help me....

Comment: You can use AVSpeechUtterance for text to speech. Sending to apple or any server won't be needed unless your requirement is other than simple text to speech.