# Is it possible to covert live streaming audio to text in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, voice-recognition

I have a live streaming audio and i need to convert it to text.Is there any api or SDK available to create an IOS app for this requirement ?

Comment: Go through this link may be help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203464/how-to-convert-speech-to-text-in-ios-sdk

Comment: Give OpenEars a try, you can find it here http://www.politepix.com/openears/

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 10, it is possible to convert speech into text using **Speech** framework. You can follow this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/).
But there are some limitations which are as follows:

- Apple limits recognition per device. The limit is not known, but you
  can contact Apple for more information.
- Apple limits recognition per app.
- If you routinely hit limits, make sure to contact Apple, they can
  probably resolve it.
- Speech recognition uses a lot of power and data.
- Speech recognition only lasts about a minute at a time.

You can also use [OpenEars](https://www.politepix.com/openears/), and [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/)