# How can I convert text to speech for using PhoneGap on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, text-to-speech

I have a list of words which I want to convert the text to voice functionality for
PhoneGap iPhone. Is there any API or Plugin for TTS? Please let me know of any alternatives.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature

Answer (score 5):

because there is not any phonegap way(javascript) way to do this i recommend using one of the native TTS opensource libraries like :

https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src

or

https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text

and then connect them to your javascript-html code with simple plugin(find more about writing a plugin : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

just simple as that!

Comment: thanks..will it work in android os??,bcoz i'm developing this app in android os for phonegap iphone..

Comment: for android you need a TTS java library there are some like : http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php and then connect it with  a simple plugin

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the Github repo for PhoneGap Plugins? (Located here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) There is indeed a TTS plugin for Android: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/TTS

Comment: thanks for the reply,even i could found the same,but i want to implement only for IOS devices rather than android..

Comment: I missed the iPhone text above. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The [cordova plugin tts](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts) works in iPhone:

```
  TTS
    .speak('hello, world!', function () {
        alert('text spoken');
    }, function (reason) {
        alert(reason);
    });
```

The plugin uses the [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer) class in iOS and works in Android, Windows Phone too.