# Convert selected Text from Textview in Speech

Tags: iphone, ios, textview, text-to-speech

I am working on **Text to speech** application in iPhone,

in which have a text View that takes input,i want user to select some portion of text from text view and my application will convert that selected text into speech.

my problem is which **SDK/API** i use to convert that selected text in speech

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature check out this link

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no SDK given by Apple . But you can use many external sdk like **iSpeech**.

http://code4app.net/ios/VoiceTTS-Demo/50cbf9f86803fa2d30000000

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the solution here in the answer. If the link ever goes dark this answer will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link,which will provide the best solution of your query.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/316701/ESpeakEngine-Objective-C-speech-synthesizer

Good Luck !!!

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the solution here in the answer. If the link ever goes dark this answer will become useless.