# How to convert a textfield to an audio file?

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, avfoundation

I have heard of AVFoundation framework (doesn't work), but is there a way to convert a textfield to an audio file.

I would love to know if there is an API for it.

Your help would you be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Refer the following link that may be help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati it does not convert the text to audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance 
                                    speechUtteranceWithString:@"Hello world"];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    [synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

instead of @"Hello World" use TextField.text

Comment: Yes, true, but I want an audio file because I want a notification to be spoken, so for a notification soundName